# www. в доменном имени

Tags: домен

Как можно сделать, чтобы при наборе домена без www. впереди например http://test.ru/ он менялся на http://www.test.ru/ то есть впереди само подставлялось www.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пропишите в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

домен соответственно Ваш.

Answer (score 1):

Редирект на стороне сервера, конечно. Следующий!

Comment: А можно как-то в .htaccess?

Comment: Можно, см. более подробный ответ сверху.